# Supremum of $f^\alpha$ with $\alpha>0$

Tags: real-analysis

I was wondering whether $\sup (f^\alpha)=(\sup f)^{\alpha}$ where $f$ is bounded and nonnegative and where $\alpha>0$?

Thanks a lot.

Math

Answer (score 1):

Yes: when $\alpha>0$, $x \mapsto x^{\alpha}$ is continuous and increasing, so it preserves the ordering on $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$. Therefore it does commute with suprema.